# How to create global numeration of records?

Tags: jasper-reports

I try to use the global numeration in subrebort, tried the "rank() over(order by eic)::integer as rank" and "REPORT_COUNT" but when I start main report with dblinks on all databases and export to csv my numeration always start from 1 every database data. How to do all numeration from 1 to end?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, do you have multiple subreports, have you tried passing parameters to subreport and then use return values. Can you create a [mcve] to show what you tried?

Comment: Sorry, but this information is confidential. I use one main report with dblinks and one subreport where use rank. I used variable REPORT_COUNT too.